# Synchronizing new calendar events always have the @removed field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm syncing calendar events using the `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` npm package with the base url `/me/calendarview/delta`. It's been working fine until a few days ago. For some reason whenever I create a new calendar event in outlook.office.com and my app syncs, the newly created calendar event has the `@removed: {reason: "deleted"}` field set.

However when I lookup that same calendar event using the Microsoft Graph Explorer that same event does NOT have the `@removed` field set. Is there any reason a newly created calendar event would look like it's being deleted during a sync?
I'm using @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client v1.3.0

Steps to recreate:

1. Create an event using the node graph client by POSTing to `/me/calendar/events`
2. Grab a delta of calendar events using `/me/calendarview/delta` with appropriate deltaLink and access token.
3. I receive 1 calendar event that has 3 fields, `@odata.type`, `id` and `@removed`. The id field matches the id of the created event in step 1.

If you need more information, let me know. This is affecting some of our users.

**Update**: I tried a workaround for this issue by calling `/me/events/<id>` for each `@removed` calendar entry I receive on a delta sync to verify if the event was truly deleted. However when I call that API via the microsoft-graph-client it returns null. If I make the same GET call via [MSFT Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/) then the event is returned.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you're getting back from Graph Explorer?

Comment: I am running into the same problem using retrofit2 implementation of MS Graph. Did you find any solution or workaround?

Comment: For me, this only happens when the new event is outside of the delta request's start-end time frame.

Comment: Hi, i am getting same error though event is not truly deleted in calendar. so,  any luck?

Comment: I never found a solution, I moved on after I implemented my workaround in the Update. Note I never supplied a start-end time frame in the delta request like @mattlaabs, just used the delta link

Comment: @user1156236 the start + end parameters are mandatory for the original request and will always be applied to future requests using the delta link.

Answer (score 3):

I left an answer on another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65348721/6806302

In short, I went off yesterday on a hunch inspired by [@mattlaabs's comment on the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641708/synchronizing-new-calendar-events-always-have-the-removed-field#comment104847477_54641708), that the startDateTime..endDateTime range of the events delta was to blame.

And in practice, that is exactly the problem. The answer is two part:

1. Changes to events not in the window always show up in the delta stream as @removed.
2. The events delta parameters are captured in a "closure", meaning subsequent requests (with a `$deltatoken`) ignore the `startDateTime..endDateTime` query parameter.

Understanding both of the above, it seems that the answer is to:

1. Create wide enough initial `startDateTime..endDateTime` windows to suite your application's needs
2. Start new events delta streams (by not providing a `$deltatoken`) at some defined interval instead of reusing the same one indefinitely